# Is there a way to share a timer?

Tags: applications

I have frequent disputes in my family of iphone users where we are waiting on each other and tensions flare. It seems we might be able to alleviate this problem if we could share a timer, perhaps 10 minute countdown timer so that we are all in the car or agreed location before that time has ellapsed and woe to the user who doesn't make it. Is there such a way to share a timer?

Comment: A shared calendar event?

Comment: You mean something like a *Coordinated Universal Time*?  You're in luck, someone has already thought of it - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time.